# MySQL Table Concurrency Solutions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multithreading

I've been looking at several different solutions to my table concurrency problems in `MySQL/PHP/InnoDB`:

I really want Process 2 to wait for Process 1 to commit before starting its own transaction and `SELECT`ing data to work on and then trying to INSERT a `UNIQUE INDEX`. So, Process 1 locks the table and Process 2 checks for the lock, and waits if a `WRITE lock` already exists with something like `sleep()`...  (I cannot use semaphores).

1. Is that it?  1b. That simple?  1c. Should I also still check for a duplicate entry when `INSERT`ing?
2. Also, do I need to check for this single `WRITE lock` **EVERYWHERE ELSE** that there are `UPDATES` and/or `INSERTS` to the table, or will this be handled automatically by making the `UPDATE/INSERT` wait? This is only done once, so making all other queries wait is the single biggest downside if this is the case.

SOLUTION BONUS THOUGHT: it would seem simpler to check for a duplicate key error when inserting, and if true, then re-`SELECT` and re-calculate a new value and try again until the `DUPLICATE KEY` error is no longer.

Comment: Check if you can use `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` (it depends on what you need to do if there is a duplicate). Also it will help if you can provide more detail on what should happen if the row already exists.

Comment: If the row already exists, the second INSERT will be rejected. If I detect the rejection, I can back off and try again... You know, like with girls.

Comment: So it is expected for the record to be removed at some point and you want to wait until then?

Comment: No, the record is permanent. And the value to be inserted is a UNIQUE INDEX, so a duplicate insert should fail naturally. The new record to be inserted is based on existing data in the table, so it is plausible that a second process could be operating at the same time, come up with the same data and try to `INSERT` before the other completes.  But each process MUST submit NEW data with an `INSERT` to the DB, therefore ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE or UPDATE will NOT work.

Comment: A second insert with the same value (or another value in the same gap) will wait for the 1-st insert's transaction to complete (or until you get a 'lock wait timeout' error...) before succeeding or failing. You can use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of catching database errors, but the locking behavior will be the same.

Comment: Could you _please_ post an answer showing how you might lock the table, and have the second process wait for the first to remove the lock... And also an example of how one could try to INSERT a new record and detect a duplicate key in a particular column? I hate asking for handouts, but none of the examples I have waded through show the waiting algorithm for the second process during a write lock OR suggest using DUPLICATE KEY errors to circumvent the use of table locks, which may be its own question.

Comment: The waiting happens in the MySQL server. From the application's point of view it just looks like the query is taking a long time to complete. I don't know how (or even if its possible) to check if a lock exists without blocking.